# R, Reading html source code using XML library and htmlTreeParse. I am new to this, so it may be a simple solution

Tags: html, r, xml

I want to be able to read in the source code to extract nodes from the HTML file.

```
library(XML)
url <- ("https://www.mlb.com/marlins")
html <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternal=T)
```

The issue is when I try this i get an error message saying : "XML content does not seem to be XML: '' "

thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

Because it is really not an XML file. To read the source code, try the following script

```
library(httr)
html <- httr::content(httr::GET("https://www.mlb.com/marlins"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rvest::read_html` to read the source.

```
data <- rvest::read_html("https://www.mlb.com/marlins")
```